# Bootstrap 4 - Change order of 5 column layout in mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a page with 3 columns as follows :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div>**Section 1**</div>
        <div>**Section 2**</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">**Section 3**</div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div>**Section 4**</div>
        <div>**Section 5**</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the order of sections in mobile as this picture :
[image]

Comment: You should change the flex-order of elements by breakpoint.
[Check out the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order)

Comment: Accept an answer so others know the question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 options...

**Use flex direction responsively:**

Use flexbox column on `lg` and larger. The `row` container *must* have a defined height. In this case I used h-100 (`height: 100%;`).

```
<div class="container vh-100">
   <div class="row h-100 flex-lg-column flex-wrap">
      <div class="col-lg-3 border flex-grow-1 overflow-auto order-3 order-lg-0">1</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 border flex-grow-1 overflow-auto order-4 order-lg-0">2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 border order-first order-lg-0 min-vh-100 overflow-auto">3</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 border flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">4</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 border flex-grow-1 overflow-auto order-last order-lg-0">5</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/WDjcxLu5bC

---

**Hack with flexbox & floats:**

This option uses floats on `lg` and larger, and the returns to flexbox on smaller screens which allows us to change the order of the cols when the layout stacks vertically. This layout is also limited to `height:100%`.

```
<div class="row d-lg-block vh-100">
    <div class="col-lg-3 float-left d-flex flex-column h-100 p-0">
        <div class="flex-grow-1 px-3 border">1</div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 px-3 border">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 float-left border order-first order-lg-0 h-100 overflow-auto">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 float-left border h-50">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 float-left border h-50">5</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/eXY3HFr5A4

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code give this order in mobile : 3,1,2,4,5 . But I need this order  : 3,4,1,2,5. Is it possible ?

Comment: I update the answer... it's a matter of adjusting the order classes